# Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'css': This element is not expected

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.2.0, frontend-error

Upgrading from Magento 2.1.7 to 2.2.0
PHP 7.0 
MySQL 5.6

Through command line I've run these commands and had no hiccups until I looked at the front end:
bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/generation/*
chmod +x bin/magento
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento maintenance:disable

I get this error message, I'm new to Magento and just an ecommerce manager, I'm updating due to some vulenrabilities, if anyone can help it would be great:

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'css': This element is not expected.
Line: 721

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'css': This element is not expected.
Line: 721

Comment: Please check error_log file is any plug in cause this error make it disable than check

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as if there's a layout file which has a `<css>` node where it shouldn't be. If you're using bash/zsh, run the grep command below and it should point you in the right direction as to where `<css>` elements are (assuming the theme is within `app/design/frontend/`)

`grep -r -i --include \*.xml '<css' app/design/frontend/`

Comment: Hi Rhys, that worked great. I got rid of those errors. Thank you.  I'm still battling with a couple of more errors however. :)

Comment: @Rhys, <css>  will not work in Magento 2.3.3 anymore?

Comment: <css> still works in 2.3.3 layouts but only in certain locations. i.e. it would work inside the <head> section of your layout XML file, but not under a <referenceBlock> section